Properties of a convergent subseries of the Harmonic series?
I have a sequence $(t_k)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that this subseries of the Harmonic series
$$S_k=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{t_j+1}$$
converges, i.e., $\lim_{k\to\infty} S_k < \infty$. (just for sanity sake, one example would be $t_k=k^2$). All I know is that $S_k$ approaches a finite limit.
Can we conclude something about the growth of $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$?
In particular, can we derive an inequality (perhaps with some "eventually" or "infinitely often" quantifiers on $k$) which state
$t_{k+1}\geq t_k + h(k)$ for some function $h$?
Intuitively, it feels like $t_k$ cannot be "too frequent". For instance, if $t_{k+1}$ and $t_k$ were always within a fixed constant $K$ of each other (namely, $t_{k+1}\leq t_k + K$), then $S_k$ would look like a the harmonic series with a prefactor of $K^{-1}$ -- that would diverge, so $t_{k+1}$ and $t_k$ cannot always be within a constant of one another. However, I'm having trouble formalizing this idea in a tractable way. This aforementioned argument would only establish the existence of at least one $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $t_{k+1}>t_k+N$, which doesn't give me a nice "eventually" or "infinitely often" statement about how most of the $t_k$ terms grow.

You might want to look at ways to measure the density of integer sequences. Start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

@EthanBolker this notion indeed looks like it will be super helpful, thank you!

@EthanBolker So it appears that the logarithmic density of $(t_j)$ must be $0$. However, I don't know how useful that is.
